# tracing a path inside a collection of 2d shapes

Tags: geometry

imagine a set of lines defining a 2d perimeter, these lines have normals (a by product of other processes) that tell me which way is outside, the opposite wanting to be solid material

in addition there are other sets of lines that specify voids inside this shape, again there are normals so I know which is inside and outside.

The lines are in no particular order and could possibly be mixed up (thou unlikely this can't be ruled out) void and perimeter lines are in no particular order - you could get a whole void shape first for example

I'm scratching my head trying to figure out an algorithm whereby I can describe a path that will at all times be X units from any other part of the path and the perimeter paths and fills all the inside area of the shape (excluding voids)

the path need not be continuous (it could be 3 or 4 separate paths for example) but ideally each path should be as long as possible.

no you don't get bonus points for guessing what this is for ;-)

Comment: You thought about something like tool path generation for pocket machining yet. From you description it seems like a similar yet not identical problem and there are a lot of very efficient Voronoi based methods for it.

Comment: if I had any idea what "pocket machining" was I might have...

Comment: When you think of a machine used for milling that has a tool that is a disk. Then that tool is used to remove material from a peace of metal. The material in a specific area which is removed is often given as a polygon. Now a path for that tool has to be generated in order to efficiently cover the polygon.

Comment: ah, okay, can you signpost me to any sites explaining algorithms for such ?

Comment: Sure, I just saw a problem, what I described is not an "online" algorithm, what you describe seems like you get more segments during computation. Is there a point/time at which all parimeters are available? Does your algorithm start before that. If your start computing paths before you have all segments your path can always end up in a void (as it could appear out of nothing). Also: If you have a gap between a wall and a void of size X+5 (where X>5), then a second pass at the gap is needed, but you would be closer than X to the other path right? (If you cover a disc of size X along your path.)

Comment: my "algorithm" consists of slicing an stl file by intersecting with two planes I get the normals from the faces and use just the verts from one of the plane intersections